# An error occurred but no ODBC error information was available

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, odbc

I have an odd issue with Excel 365 v16.0.16827.20278 installed on a host machine. When trying to access an ODBC source, used successfully by several other individuals, Excel throws the error

> An error occurred but no ODBC error information was available

This error can only be triggered from Excel on this single computer from this users profile. Knowing that there are some heavy handed solutions to this e.g., rebuild local computer profile and possibly reinstall Office. I was curious if there was more surgical options.

On the same computer I can do the following without issue:

- Perform a source test successfully from odbcad32.exe
- Run a PowerShell Script to pull one record using the odbc source as the troubled user
- Use Microsoft Access for 365 and use the same ODBC source to pull data
- Run Excel as myself in my own profile on the same computer to use the ODBC connection

I attempted to run a trace using odbcad32.exe under the **Tracing** tab with **Machine-wide tracing for all users identities** checked but no log was created. This is in contrast to the tracing test I did on other computers.

Using this ODBC source requires a VPN connection to be established. What is interesting is that the error is the same whether or not the VPN is connected.

My conclusion using the above information is that Excel is the issue under this one local user profile. However, I don't know where to go with that information. The application itself appears to be working fine so repair/reinstall doesn't seem like a viable approach. Rebuilding the local profile is a last resort that I am trying to avoid for the time being.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer for error messages, perhaps the ODBC driver has put a message in there. If not, try to find an update to the driver - which one is it?

Comment: Good point. I should have mentioned that I did check event viewer and no correlating events were found. The deployment instructions we have are for using v17 of the SQL Server driver to match the 2017 sql server version we are using as that is the environment the report were developed in. I might be able to find another version just to try. Not a crazy idea. I wanted some sort of cache to clear for this but I am not aware of any that exists.

Comment: Something else to consider (that has bitten me in the past) is that there are 64 bit and 32 bit odbc drivers that are [configured completely separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/odbc-tool-displays-32-bit-64-bit).  I am not saying this is related to your problem but it might be.

Comment: One tool I have used in the past is to enable tracing for the ODBC driver. See this [example link](https://docs.devart.com/odbc/sqlserver/enable_odbc_tracing.htm).

Comment: Appreciate the consideration. That is not the issue here. We are using x64 to match the office installation and odbc. The exposure to application to the source hasnt been the problem. Excel using it has.

Comment: @harrymc I mentioned that I used that specifically in my post. `I attempted to run a trace using odbcad32.exe`. It got no results which leads me to conclude that the ODBC itself is not the problem.

Comment: I thought about running procmon but I am getting to the point of diminishing returns.

Comment: You mean that you ran with tracing and got nothing? You should have gotten something.

Comment: @harrymc Literally nothing which is why I do not think its an ODBC issue.

Comment: The conclusion you're trying to avoid seems valid to me, that this is a profile corruption. Try as a last verification to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).